# Monitor installation of a software

Tags: windows, installation, windows-registry

I would like to know if you guys would know a tool that allows to know what's actually going on during the installation of a software on Windows. I would like to know which files have been created/modified, which/where binaries have been copied, and which registry keys have been created/modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Install-Tracker](http://www.crystalidea.com/install-tracker-installation-monitor). That should be exactly what you are looking for.